# JMeter how to set Config Element for JSON as payload

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter for load Testing my Application .

As part of payload i am sending 3 parameters to the REST Webservice call

```
ordersplitjson  = {"highPriceVendor": "VC4 Raj","vendors": {"T1": [{"item_ids_": "194","leaf": [{"orderid": "14101519","cust_id": "22"}],"vendor_id": "9"}]}}
customer_id  =  22
homedelivery  = Yes
```

I am loadtesting the Application with 100 users with a Ramp Time for 2 seconds .

This is the way i have configured and this works fine for static payload

[image]

As part of load Test , i want to login as different user for every request 
(Means for every request i want to send different parameters )

I guess i cant use **CSV DataSet Config** as i have a JSON as a payload

could anybody please let me know how to achive this load test with different payloads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should still be able to use CSV Data Set Config by following one of below approaches

- Option 1: change "Delimiter" from default comma `,' to something else which won't be in your JSON payload, i.e. | , put your JSON payloads into CSV file and use them as it.
- Option 2: You don't necessarily need to have the full JSON in the CSV Data Set element, it can be configured to read multiple values into multiple variables, i.e. your CSV file will be something like

  ```
  VC4 Raj, T1, 194, 141519, 22, 9
  ```

And Variable Names in CSV Data Set Config will be

```
highPriceVendor, vendors, item_ids_, orderid, cust_id, vendor_id
```

In that case you can configure your request body as:

```
{"highPriceVendor": "${highPriceVendor}","vendors": {"${vendors}": [{"item_ids_": "${item_ids_}","leaf": [{"orderid": "${orderid}","cust_id": "${cust_id}"}],"vendor_id": "${vendor_id}"}]}}
```

See [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) guide for instructions on the second approach.

Comment: Thank you very much sir , Option 1 seems good . Thanks once again .